# Does every NP-complete prob. admit a polynomial-time restriction?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, restrictions

I have to answer this question as a homework assignment but I am finding very little material to work with. I understand what is a NP-complete problem and what is a restriction. In my opinion, this statement is true, because you can always restrict the problem in order to "make the problem easier". But I'm looking at it with a bird's eye view... Can anyone help me make some progress finding the answer to this question?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: To confirm - a "restriction" would be an infinite subset of the NP language that belongs to P?

Comment: Given two problems R and P, the problem R is a restriction of P if the instance set of R is a subset of the instance set of P. For example 3-SAT is a restriction of SAT.

Comment: Does the trivial restriction of the empty set count? That's definitely in P, but it's not "interesting."

Comment: You mean as in, for the TSP problem, for example, having a graph with no vertices?
What if we take a step back and have the set with only one value?

Comment: Even more abstractly, consider any problem whose instance set is empty (take any impossible problem, or the trivial problem where the answer is always no). The empty set is a subset of all problems, so the "empty problem" is trivially a restriction of any problem. However, it's not an "interesting" restriction in that it doesn't tell you anything about how to extract an "interesting" subproblem from an arbitrary NP problem.

Comment: I think that counts, because in my opinion, this exercise is meant to show if we understood the concept of restrictions. And it is a very general answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer - consider the "empty problem," a problem whose instance set is empty. Since the empty set is a subset of every set, this problem technically counts as a restriction of any language (including languages not in **NP**). It's also a problem in **P**; you can build a polynomial-time TM that always rejects its input. Therefore, every problem in **NP** has a polynomial-time restriction.

What I'm still curious about, though, is whether every **NP** problem whose instance set is infinite has a polynomial-time restriction whose instance set is also infinite. That's a more interesting question, IMHO, and I don't currently have an answer.

Hope this helps!